# Как правильно подключить стороннюю библиотеку C++

Tags: c++, mingw, codeblocks

Скачал библиотеку NTL ( http://shoup.net/ntl/doc ). В туториале по установке на Windows было показано, как создается статическая библиотека на основе заголовочных файлов и их реализаций. А что делать дальше? Как, к примеру, подключать эту библиотеку #include ? У меня MinGW на CodeBlocks. Можно ли статью или совет, как правильно такие библиотеки подключать. Вот ссылка на то, где объясняется про эту сборку в .lib (я не понял, что делать дальше): http://shoup.net/ntl/doc/tour-win.html

Comment: #include к lib имеет мало отношения. Определитесь какая именно у вас среда, потому что подключение lib в разных средах может происходить по разному.

Comment: @Владимир Мартьянов CodeBlocks

Comment: Играет роль, скорее, не среда, а пара компилятор-линкер. И да, для разных пар подключение происходит по-разному.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для mingw (который GCC + GNU ld), который, как я думаю, используется у Вас в codeblocks нужно:

1. использовать подходящий путь до `.h`-файлов, в codeblocks это  "Project" -> "Build Options" -> "Search directories" ->  "Compiler". Или напрямую в gcc через флаг `-I`: `gcc -I/путь/до/каталога/c/заголовками/библиотеки -I/путь/до/другой/библиотеки/ ... -c ваш_файл.c`
2. использовать подходящий путь до библиотеки. В случае статической библиотеки, путь до `.a`/`.lib` можно указать прямо полностью:

   gcc -o ваш_выполняемый_файл ваш_файл.o /путь/до/библиотеки/libsome.a

Обратите внимание, что файлы библиотек должны указываться *после* объектных файлов, иначе вы рискуете получить [ошибку линковки](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/specify_the_libraries_for_the_linker_to_use).

В codeblocks пути до библиотек находятся на соседней вкладке от путей для компилятора из п.1

Вот [здесь](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/a3-using-libraries-with-codeblocks/) процесс настройки CodeBlocks показан с картинками (на английском)